# Java nested Map declaration - what's inner Map concrete type

Tags: java, java-7

I have a map `foo` declared like below.

```
private final Map<String, Map<String, Bar>> foo = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, Map<String, Bar>>();
```

Since I don't want the data type look exposing the concrete data type, so I didn't declare it as:

```
private final Map<String, ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, Bar>> foo = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, Bar>>();
```

My questions is what's the actual type of the inner map? If I want the inner map same type as outer one (ConcurrentSkipListMap). How should I do it without exposing the concrete data type?

Comment: You've just created an empty `ConcurrentSkipListMap` that maps a `String` to another `Map`. The actual type depends on what you put in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared the outer map as `Map` as opposed to `ConcurrentSkipListMap` to hide it's implementation - you can do just the same with the inner map.

The (outer) map you've created is empty - the only known thing about it is that it maps `String` to `Map` (any class implementing `Map`), therefore your question is wrong - there is no actual inner map (not yet, anyway) and the only thing you know about it without any checks is that it's a `Map<String, Bar>`

It's worth noting that unless you have very specific requirements that mandate usage of specific implementations, you should be using interfaces to declare variables.